# why sbt doesn't compile the code and the main libraries aren't even recognised?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sbt

This code demonstrates a Spark application that performs language ranking based on Wikipedia articles. It utilizes RDDs for distributed processing and leverages Spark's parallel processing capabilities. Nevertheless, it appears an error of

> Extracting structure failed: Build status: Error
>
> sbt task failed, see log for details

and none of the imports work when I try to run the scala script:

```scala
package wikipedia

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

case class WikipediaArticle(title: String, text: String)

object WikipediaRanking {

  val langs = List(
    "JavaScript", "Java", "PHP", "Python", "C#", "C++", "Ruby", "CSS",
    "Objective-C", "Perl", "Scala", "Haskell", "MATLAB", "Clojure", "Groovy")

  val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("wikipedia").setMaster("local[*]")
  val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
  sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
  // Hint: use a combination of `sc.textFile`, `WikipediaData.filePath` and `WikipediaData.parse`
  val wikiRdd: RDD[WikipediaArticle] = sc.textFile(WikipediaData.filePath).map(l => WikipediaData.parse(l)).cache()

  /** Returns the number of articles on which the language `lang` occurs.
    *  Hint1: consider using method `aggregate` on RDD[T].
    *  Hint2: should you count the "Java" language when you see "JavaScript"?
    *  Hint3: the only whitespaces are blanks " "
    *  Hint4: no need to search in the title :)
    */
  def occurrencesOfLang(lang: String, rdd: RDD[WikipediaArticle]): Int = {
    rdd.aggregate(0)((sum, article) => sum + isFound(article, lang), _+_)
  }

  def isFound(article: WikipediaArticle, lang: String): Int = if(article.text.split(" ").contains(lang)) 1 else 0

  /* (1) Use `occurrencesOfLang` to compute the ranking of the languages
   *     (`val langs`) by determining the number of Wikipedia articles that
   *     mention each language at least once. Don't forget to sort the
   *     languages by their occurrence, in decreasing order!
   *
   *   Note: this operation is long-running. It can potentially run for
   *   several seconds.
   */
  def rankLangs(langs: List[String], rdd: RDD[WikipediaArticle]): List[(String, Int)] = {
    val ranks = langs.map(lang => (lang, occurrencesOfLang(lang, rdd)))
    //for{ lang <- langs; occ = occurrencesOfLang(lang, rdd) if occ != 0} yield (lang, occ)
    ranks.sortBy(_._2).reverse
  }

  /* Compute an inverted index of the set of articles, mapping each language
     * to the Wikipedia pages in which it occurs.
     */
  def makeIndex(langs: List[String], rdd: RDD[WikipediaArticle]): RDD[(String, Iterable[WikipediaArticle])] = {
    val list = rdd.flatMap(article => for( lang <- langs if isFound(article, lang) == 1) yield (lang, article))
    list.groupByKey()
  }

  /* (2) Compute the language ranking again, but now using the inverted index. Can you notice
   *     a performance improvement?
   *
   *   Note: this operation is long-running. It can potentially run for
   *   several seconds.
   */
  def rankLangsUsingIndex(index: RDD[(String, Iterable[WikipediaArticle])]): List[(String, Int)] = {
    val ranks = index.mapValues(_.size).collect().toList.sortBy(-_._2)
    ranks
  }


  /* (3) Use `reduceByKey` so that the computation of the index and the ranking are combined.
   *     Can you notice an improvement in performance compared to measuring *both* the computation of the index
   *     and the computation of the ranking? If so, can you think of a reason?
   *
   *   Note: this operation is long-running. It can potentially run for
   *   several seconds.
   */
  def rankLangsReduceByKey(langs: List[String], rdd: RDD[WikipediaArticle]): List[(String, Int)] = {
    val list = rdd.flatMap(article => for( lang <- langs if isFound(article, lang) == 1) yield (lang, 1))
    list.reduceByKey(_+_).collect().toList.sortBy(_._2).reverse
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    /* Languages ranked according to (1) */
    val langsRanked: List[(String, Int)] = timed("Part 1: naive ranking", rankLangs(langs, wikiRdd))
    langsRanked.foreach(println)

    /* An inverted index mapping languages to wikipedia pages on which they appear */
    def index: RDD[(String, Iterable[WikipediaArticle])] = makeIndex(langs, wikiRdd)

    /* Languages ranked according to (2), using the inverted index */
    val langsRanked2: List[(String, Int)] = timed("Part 2: ranking using inverted index", rankLangsUsingIndex(index))
    langsRanked2.foreach(println)

    /* Languages ranked according to (3) */
    val langsRanked3: List[(String, Int)] = timed("Part 3: ranking using reduceByKey", rankLangsReduceByKey(langs, wikiRdd))
    langsRanked3.foreach(println)

    /* Output the speed of each ranking */
    println(timing)
    sc.stop()
  }

  val timing = new StringBuffer
  def timed[T](label: String, code: => T): T = {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val result = code
    val stop = System.currentTimeMillis()
    timing.append(s"Processing $label took ${stop - start} ms.\n")
    result
  }
}
```

Also, I share the `build.sbt` and the `WikipediaData` object:

```scala
name := "YourProjectName"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation")

lazy val courseId = settingKey[String]("Course ID")
courseId := "e8VseYIYEeWxQQoymFg8zQ"

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-sbt" % "sbt" % "1.1.6",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-lang3" % "3.12.0", // Apache Commons Lang
  "jline" % "jline" % "2.14.6"
)
```

```scala
package wikipedia

import java.io.File

object WikipediaData {

  private[wikipedia] def filePath = {
    new File(this.getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("wikipedia/wikipedia.dat").toURI).getPath
  }

  private[wikipedia] def parse(line: String): WikipediaArticle = {
    val subs = "</title><text>"
    val i = line.indexOf(subs)
    val title = line.substring(14, i)
    val text  = line.substring(i + subs.length, line.length-16)
    WikipediaArticle(title, text)
  }
}
```

I tried to try the different versions of **JDK** (now using OpenJDK **1.8**), checked for the compatible packages of **Scala**, **Spark** and **Sbt** and managed to declare all these tools on "Project File" menu. Also, tried to test the similar solutions on other Stack OverFlow responses, but doesn't work yet.

Edit: The messages of error are the following ones:

1. Whenever I "load SBT changes" or prompt "sbt run", the result is the following:

[image: Screenshot of SBT build error]

2. Afterwards, I run the project on WikipediaRanking.scala, but obtain the following:

[image: Screenshot of run and execute error]

Comment: could you edit your post and share what were the steps you follow to get the error such as the command to build and execute? also add the full error message

Comment: Done. Hope it is useful to find what we need to make it work.

Comment: The first screenshot just show a pretty generic error message. I think if you click in the element with the text `Coursera_Scala_Spark` that is in the left panel it will show a full descriptive message saying what is happening. I would also suggest that try to execute `sbt run` from the command-line instead of intellij to see if you get the same error

Comment: Thank you! I get this error from intellij: "[error]    org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml _2.12, _2.11
[error]    org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators _2.11, _2.12
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Conflicting cross-version suffixes in: org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml, org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators"

Comment: when i do "sbt run" on cmd, it packages as [info] Packaging C:\Users\Enrique\target\scala-2.12\enrique_2.12-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar don't know why. I declared on my built.sbt that I am using Scala 2.11.8. I don't know what drives it to interact with Scala 2.12 (which I don't even have installed in my computer)

Comment: please edit the post and paste the full message as part of the question. in that way anyone else trying to understand your issue will have more context and will not need to read the comments. Also, as you can see, here the formatting is not the best. you can also try to use [sbt dependencyTree](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/sbt-dependency-tree) who is adding those libs and versions as dependency

Comment: I think the problem is the ["org.scala-sbt" % "sbt" % "1.1.6"](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.1.6) dependency. If you look at the `Compile Dependencies` section, you will see that this version depends on `scala 2.12` and you are setting `2.11` as the scala version of your project. Downgrading to sbt `0.99.4` or upgrading scala to `2.12.16` should fix it. scala `2.12.17` will produce conflicts because it depends on `scala-xml 2.1.0` and some other libraries depends on `scala-xml 1.0.6`

Comment: In the first error image, please click on the "Coursera_Scala_Spark" line for the full sbt error log details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error

```scala
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in ProjectRef(uri("file:/path/to/your/project/"), "name-of-the-project"):
[error]    org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml _2.12, _2.11
[error]    org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators _2.11, _2.12
```

because of the following libraries:

- [`"org.scala-sbt" % "sbt" % "1.1.6"`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.1.6)
- [`"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0"`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/2.1.0)
- [`"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0"`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.11/2.1.0)

If you look at the compile dependencies of `sbt 1.1.6`, you will find that one of the dependencies is [`scala_2.12.6`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.12.6). This will create conflicts with `spark-core` and `spark-sql` because there is no release for `scala 2.12` (when you create a scala library, you can release it for different scala versions which is called [cross building](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Cross-Build.html)). So, when **sbt** tries to find the correct transitive dependency, it says I need `scala-xml` and `scala-parser-combinators` for scala `2.11` and `2.12` at the same time, which is not possible.

---

You have two ways of solving this issue:

#### Downgrade sbt to a version that depends on scala 2.11

Based on the name of your project, sounds like you are taking a course and the goal is to learn [apache-spark](https://spark.apache.org/) for [scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/) and not `sbt`. In this case, the last release for sbt depending on scala 2.11 was [0.99.4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.99.4). If the project examples that you have to download to do some exercises depends on features that were added in `sbt 1.x.x`, maybe you could try [sbt 1.0.0-M4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.0.0-M4) that stills depends on `scala 2.11`.

#### Upgrade `spark-core` and `spark-sql` to a version compatible with scala 2.12

The first release compatible with `scala 2.12` for [spark-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.12) and [spark-sql](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.12) is `2.4.0` which is not far away from the one that you have selected. Not sure which changes were introduced. If you are following a tutorial, some differences could be found on how to do some stuff, blocking your learning until you figure out how to do it.

---

In addition to this, scala `2.11` is a bit old. The [available versions page](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/all.html) shows that `2.11` (last release was on November 9, 2017) and `2.12` (last release was on June 7, 2023) are being maintained. Only scala `2.13.x` and `3` are being developed. This means that if you try to use an old version of scala, you might have to deal with incompatibilities between libraries like the one you are having now.

Maybe there is a new course with updated versions of `scala` and `spark`. The latest version for spark today is [3.4.1](https://spark.apache.org/news/spark-3-4-1-released.html), which is compatible with [scala 2.12](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.12/3.4.1) and [scala 2.13](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.13/3.4.1). No official release for scala 3 yet.

Comment: Thank you so much! It did solve the issue with scala - spark - sbt compatibility

Comment: Now I have one more issue that got me stuck. I will add an Edit 2 section on my question. The program compilation asked for SLF4J and Log4j in my Build.sbt . That's what I did, I checked the versions added were reliable and compatible. Nevertheless, I get a quite long error related to those libraries. I have looked up everywhere, but couldn't come up with a solution...

Comment: Please, if this answer is enough to solve the issue you had, create a new post showing what's the new problem you are having. Editing the question that was solved will create confusion to the ones that have the new error you get and find my answer as the solution

Comment: Sure, I'll do that. I saw you edited the question and left it neat. Thank you again!!!